# Calculating the euclidean distance of each pair of vectors in a tensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a Tensor of size (4000000,3,90) which is , 4mil rows, 3 columns, and in each cell there is a 90 dim vector.

I would like to calculate the Euclidean distance of each 2 vectors in a row and save the distances in a distance matrix. The goal is to know which 2 vectors are the closest.

I am using `PyTorch` and I want to know what is the most efficient way/best practice.

### Edit:

It doesn't have to be the euclidean norm it can also be dot product

My thoughts:
I thought about calculating to each pair the norm, and for the distance between V2 , V3 for example, put it in the 1st column , and V1,V3 put in 2nd column and so on.. and then take the `min()` of all entries for a row to know which vector is the farthest.I'm wondering if there is an efficient/built in pytroch way to do it or should i just do a for loop

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @slothrop this isnt the norm i asked for

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You talk about "2 vectors" but your tensor seems to have 3. Is one assigned as a reference vector? Does the computation only happen along the last two axes? Or are you trying to do a 40Mx40M comparison? Provide a workable small scale example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the Euclidean (or 2-norm) you can use `torch.linalg.vector_norm()`. You provide the dimension over which the norm should be computed and the other dimensions are automatically treated as batch-dimensions.

But you want to compute the norm over distances between vectors, which you need to calculate first. You can write a function that does the calculation for each row and then vectorize it:

```py
import torch as tor
from itertools import combinations

#calculate norm of distances for each row with 3 vectors
def vector_distances(x: tor.Tensor) -> tor.Tensor:
    distances = tor.zeros_like(x)
    # calculate all the distance vectors (here: 3)
    for i, pairing_of_vectors in enumerate(combinations(range(3), r =2)):
        vec_1 = x[pairing_of_vectors[0]]
        vec_2 = x[pairing_of_vectors[1]]
        distances[i] = vec_1 - vec_2
    
    # calculate the norms of your vectors
    norm = tor.linalg.vector_norm(distances, dim = 1)
    return norm

# vectorize function so you can run it over all rows at the same time
vectorized_distances = tor.func.vmap(vector_distances)

# assuming your Tensor is called data
distances = vectorized_distances(data)
```

It might be possible to use `torch.nn.PairwiseDistance()`(which basically does the same as my function `vector_distances()`) but I did not manage to vectorize it.

Note also, that this code works well for 3 vectors (per row) because there are three different distances between 3 vectors so the tensor `distance` can have the same shape as your row data. For more vectors, one would need to to calculate the number of distance vectors (e.g. with `math.comb()` and create a distance tensor with that size.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, for each of the `40000000` rows, you want to be able to know the minimal distance over `3` vectors of dim `90`. Your output would be :

- a vector of length `40M` with all minimal distances
- a `(40M, 2)` matrix with the corresponding indices (`(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)` or `(1, 2)`)

Let us start by solving a more simple problem, find the minimal distance and indices for a `(3, 90)` tensor (could be seen as a sub-problem of the first one). The following script shows how to compute a `3x3` distance matrix using dummy axis (see the link in comment for more info) and how to extract the information you need using `torch.topk`:

```
X = torch.randn(3, 90)

# https://sparrow.dev/adding-a-dimension-to-a-tensor-in-pytorch/
Xi = X[:, None, :]
Xj = X[None, :, :]
# Compute the 3x3 distance matrix
distances = ((Xi - Xj) ** 2).sum(dim=-1)

print("Distance matrix:")
print(distances)

# Fill diagonal with inf to avoid matching a point with itself
distances = distances.fill_diagonal_(float("inf"))

# Compute the nearest neighbor of each point and associated distances
# See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.topk.html
knn = distances.topk(k=1, largest=False)

values = knn.values.squeeze(-1) # Minimal distances for each point
indices = knn.indices.squeeze(-1) # Indices of the nearest points for each point
argmin = values.argmin() # Index of the point for which the minimal distance is minimal

minimal_distance = values[argmin] # The global minimum of distances
indices = torch.tensor([argmin, indices[argmin]]) # The indices of the points where the minimum is reached

print()
print(f"Minimal distance: {minimal_distance}")
print(f"Indices of the nearest points: {indices}")
```

Output:

```
Distance matrix:
tensor([[  0.0000, 208.3901, 204.1861],
        [208.3901,   0.0000, 195.4102],
        [204.1861, 195.4102,   0.0000]])

Minimal distance: 195.4102020263672
Indices of the nearest points: tensor([1, 2])
```

Now, you want to apply the same operation but for a `(n_rows, 3, 90)` tensor and outputs min_distances of size `(n_rows)` and corresponding indices `(n_rows, 2)`. The following function does the job. It is pretty similar to the script above except that we cannot apply `fill_diagonal_` to a `(n_rows, 3, 3)`, I followed the solution of https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-diagonal-of-each-matrix-in-a-batch-to-0/113646

```
def compute_distances(X):

    n_rows, n_cols, dim = X.shape

    Xi = X[:, :, None, :]
    Xj = X[:, None, :, :]
    distances = ((Xi - Xj) ** 2).sum(dim=-1)
    # distances is a (n_rows, n_cols, n_cols) tensor

    # Check that the shape of distances is correct
    assert distances.shape == (n_rows, n_cols, n_cols)

    # We want to apply fill_diagonal_ to each matrix in the batch
    # https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-diagonal-of-each-matrix-in-a-batch-to-0/113646
    value = float('inf')
    mask = torch.eye(n_cols).repeat(n_rows, 1, 1).bool()
    distances[mask] = value

    # Now, we want to find the nearest neighbor for each point
    knn = distances.topk(1, largest=False)

    # Same as in the previous script: compute minimal distance from each point
    # then corresponding indices, then global minimum
    values = knn.values.squeeze(-1)
    indices = knn.indices.squeeze(-1)
    argmin = values.argmin(dim=1)

    min_distances = values[torch.arange(n_rows), argmin]
    min_indices_0 = indices[torch.arange(n_rows), argmin]
    min_indices_1 = argmin

    min_indices = torch.stack([min_indices_0, min_indices_1], dim=1)

    return min_distances, min_indices
```

Let's test it on an example:

```
X = torch.randn(40000, 3, 90) # 40000 rows, 3 columns, 90 dimensions

# Apply the function
min_distances, min_indices = compute_distances(X)

# Manually compute the distances
Xi = X[:, :, None, :]
Xj = X[:, None, :, :]
distances =  ((Xi - Xj) ** 2).sum(dim=-1)

# Check that the minimal distances and indices are correct for a given row index
index = 1234

print(f"Minimal distance: {min_distances[index]}")
print(f"Indices of the nearest points: {min_indices[index]}")
print(f"Distance matrix:")
print(distances[index])
```

Output:

```
Minimal distance: 214.47735595703125
Indices of the nearest points: tensor([2, 1])
Distance matrix:
tensor([[  0.0000, 223.2144, 221.7425],
        [223.2144,   0.0000, 214.4774],
        [221.7425, 214.4774,   0.0000]])
```

Hope it will help you solve your problem.